# Base class to handle derived class's controls and events

Tags: vb.net, winforms, oop

I'm working on 4 winform forms that have 5 common combobox controls. The logic for filling and handling the combobox control events is identical on all 4 of the winform forms. The code is interrelated...so for example, combobox 1 controls filling combobox 2 and fills a few text boxes, combobox 2 affects combobox3...etc.

The reason I'd like to combine the code is that others have changed one or two of the forms without updating the others...so the code is becoming a mess. Unfortunately, the controls aren't located near each other...so I can't make some sort of composite control.

I was thinking of adding the common code in a base class that inherits Form, and then have the 4 forms inherit from the base class but I ran into issues accessing the events in the base class and the combobox code accesses other controls on the forms that aren't in the base class.

What is the best way to accomplish this (within the constraints of not being able to completely rewrite this in MVC, or ripping these forms completely apart, etc.)? Should I use a base class? If so, how do you access the controls in the derived class from the base class and how do you get the base class to respond to the event handlers?

I was thinking I could call `MyBase.EventMethod` for the derived class's event handler?

Comment: Use a `UserControl` with all the comboboxes and supply all logic in that class.

Comment: Post some code to make your problem clear. It is not clear why can't you use a common base class?

Comment: @OneFineDay - I can't use a UserControl, I explained that the controls aren't located near each other on the forms.

Comment: @Sriram - I will in a little while, but essentially I get errors in the base class stating they need a With Friends clause...if I add them, then both the base class and derived class have the With statements...

Comment: unfortunately I can't seem to edit my own question (I don't post many questions)...but I get a NUll reference exception to the derived form's controls when in the base class...even if I add "   Friend WithEvents Cbo_CardABSL As System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox" statement in the base class.